# Solutions for DOMPDF Rendering Dynamic Table Slowly

Tags: php, html, performance, html-table, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to render HTML tables. However, because large tables we'll say greater that 150 rows render extremely slowly. I know this is a known issue for DOMPDF.

Does anyone know of any good work around?
Maybe using a different html to pdf converter?
How to write html code that is formatted like a table without using a table?

Any idea?

Comment: How slow is it? A few seconds? Tens of seconds? Part of the slowness will be the complexity of the table. It would be easier to suggest changes that could improve performance with dompdf if we had a code sample.

Answer (score 3):

Using big and unnecessary css-files caused slowness for me. I was using 8000 line css-file. Example 1-page pdf rendered 5.5 seconds.

I removed my css-links from html-template and made a custom css-file containing only things I need ie. bootstrap's grid, table and panel css.
Now rendering takes less than 1 second so over 80% render time improvement.